# Get all `Timestamp` from 5am today

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my table that is set as curret_timestamp, so the mysql database automatically puts the timestamp in when a record is created.

I need to get all records for the current day.  At the moment I have my WHERE like this:

`WHERE r.ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

But this is giving me the last 24hrs.  Which means that in the morning it still shows yesterday.  So how can I say 'Give me all `r.ts` from 5am this morning?'

Comment: I realise I could change the interval to 12 hours, but I'd rather be more specific

Answer (score 1):

If you want all records with a timestamp from the current day later than 5am use

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE r.ts > CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 05:00:00')
```

If you want all records with a timestamps since the last time it was 5am use

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE r.ts > CONCAT(IF(CURTIME() < '05:00:00', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), CURDATE()), ' 05:00:00')
```

The queries result only in different results from 00:00:00 - 04:59:59, so the first and easier alternative should be used, if there are no queries in that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
select * from t    
WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(t.ts,'%Y:%m:%d') = DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y:%m:%d') AND
DATE_FORMAT(t.ts,'%H:%i:%s') > STR_TO_DATE('05:00:00', '%H:%i:%s');
```

Explaination: The first condition check for current date and match it. And than it check for time it must be greater than morning 5 AM.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c0c1/4)

Comment: @Chud37: updated my post with sql fiddle and query. Now it is perfect